# Creating 3 option dynamic dependant dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a small project I'd like to get done concerning the use of a MySQL Database.

I want to create a two option dropdown menu. Each of these will contain a list of all the countries in the world, but based on the combination of options they select, they will be sent to a different page on our website.

Since the number of possibilities is going to be so large (200 x 200 countries = 40,000 potential answers) we decided it would be best to seed a MySQL database with all this information and then have simple code on our website which would pull them to the right place depending on the option they picked. Unfortunately none of us here have any experience with something like this, so we are looking for someone who can help us to:

1) Create the HTML and Javascript that will sit on our website

2) Establish the connection from the MySQL Database to our website to be able to pull in the values

3) Make the values selected point to the URLs we choose

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear, I dont think that combination will take much time in any language.
Why do you want to redirect to different page for each combination ?

Comment: Create a php page where u connect with the database and with a Query u can SELECT what u want with the user option selected. The option menu can be done in html written in php with echo for example. To the url u can add as parameter a php var with the option the menu choose. Basically thats it, u then read the url and with the parameter u go to the page u want

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for the dependent dropdown. In fact, you don't need to do more simply on change event you need to get a value of selected drop-down and make an ajax call on the database in return data from your database on bases of that value then you can append data on success in another dropdown and can continue this process for more dependent dropdown.

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
$country_result = $conn->query('select * from countries');
?>

<select name="country" id="countries-list">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
        if ($country_result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $country_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["country_name"]; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
        </select>
</br></br></br>
        <select name="state" id="states-list">
            <option value=''>Select State</option>
        </select>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
$('#countries-list').on('change', function(){
    var country_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_states.php",
    data:'country_id='+country_id,
    success: function(result){
        $("#states-list").html(result);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```